# HDMI Audio output problem

Tags: 12.10, sound, hdmi

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 and having trouble with the audio output through HDMI on my Acer Aspire one 722.  It's using an AMD c-60.  I was able to add in the `radeon.audio=1` kernel parameter, which was supposed to enable HDMI audio playback but even after running `update-grub` and rebooting, the problem persists when I choose HDMI as the audio output after plugging in my HDMI cable.

At this point, I'm not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install the actual proprietary drivers for your Radeon card to get HDMI audio working properly. Also `pavucontrol` allows you to tweak the audio settings much better than the default volume control.

In a Terminal window type these commands:

```
cd /tmp && wget -O amd-driver-12-6-x86_64.run http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-12-6-x86.x86_64.run
chmod +x amd-driver-12-6-x86_64.run
sudo sh amd-driver-12-6-x86_64.run

sudo aticonfig --initial -f
```

The last command will let you know if installation worked OK.

Comment: I was thinking about that but last time I installed proprietary drivers, it disabled sleep mode for my laptop.  Will the same happen here?

Answer (score 0):

`radeon.audio=1` seemed to work for me, but I noticed you said you ran `update-grub`... It probably overwrote the setting with the defaults once again. (caught that when I also ran `update-grub`)

Hope it helps :D